# ACTION_SEND Intent with custom extras causing other apps to crash

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm implementing an option for sharing content from my app. When the user presses the share button the following code is executed.

```
public static void openShareIntent(Context context, String text, Wish wish)
{
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");       
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    share.putExtra("share_wish", wish);

    startIntent(context, share);
}
```

I'm setting one special extra for my Intent, that is object `wish` witch implements the `Parcelable` interface.

This object contains some extra information. I want to use this information if the user selects my app (current app actually sharing content) from the available apps for sharing `text/plain`.

But the problem is that all other popular apps (Facebook, Twitter, ...) and built-in apps (Messaging) crash when I include my `Parcable` object. It's not my applications that crashes, other apps are throwing `quit unexpectedly` error.

When I call my `SharingActivity` with some extra name that is not known to this Activity, it does not crash. It just ignore that extra.

[Wish object source code](https://gist.github.com/pzagor2/5108651)

Am I doing something wrong or what?
Is this not possible because other apps don't know my `Wish` object?

Comment: Post your logcat. There's a good chance your `Parcelable` implementation is incorrect, so the other apps crash when attempting to unmarshal the object.

Comment: are **text/plain** and **Parcelable** same..? I don't think you can do that..

Comment: Nothing show up in LogCat. I'm sure other app can't unmarshal the object, because they don't know it. But they shouldn't even try it. @ngesh I suspect the same. But i hope this is not the case.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2141166/262462

Comment: "nothing shows up in logcat": Unlikely, given that you say there's a crash. Any filters set? -- I don't see what "text/plain" has to do with Parcelable or why they should be the same. -- Extras are collected in a Bundle, so apps processing an Intent will most likely just look for the keys they understand, otherwise I would have made other observations in the past. -- Why not post your `Wish` code?

Comment: The Parcelable is definitely implemented correctly, because I'm using it all over my app. And i get the correct data when selecting my application from the list.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether Parcelables work within your app. Once you send the Intent out of your app, you're crossing process boundaries, and you need to provide proper AIDL so the other process can unmarshal it. Without checking, I seem to remember that Android attempts to unmarshal the extras as the Intent is received, so it could be failing right there.

Comment: BTW it's not my application that creases. It's other applications.

Comment: Have you played around with different `describeContents()` return values? -- Yes it's clear that other applications crash. Maybe they consider your Parcelable to be something else e.g. because of the describeContents value you have chosen.

Comment: @ClassStacker i did not. I decided to put the object in Bundle as suggested by CommonsWare, and everything is working as expected.

Comment: Certainly an excellent choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the problem is that all other popular apps (Facebook, Twitter, ...) and built-in apps (Messaging) crash when I include my Parcable object.

Never pass a custom `Parcelable` object to an app that lacks your `Parcelable` class definition.

> Is this not possible because other apps don't know my Wish object?

Correct.

Instead, pass an *identifier* (string, `int`, whatever) that `SharingActivity` can use to find your `Wish` from your central data model.

Or, instead of creating a custom `Wish`, use a `Bundle` to represent the "wish", as `Bundle` has a common class definition across all apps.

Comment: Tnx. I just tested and the Bundle version woks just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could just put your data in a bundle and send it with intent as well.
eg:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putParcelable("object_key", yourObject);
shareIntent.putExtra("bundle_key", b);
```